# Vue 3 TypeScript - Module '"XX' declares 'YY' locally, but it is not exported

Tags: typescript, interface, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a situation in Vue 3, TypeScript, composition API: I have the entries.model.ts from which I am importing two interfaces.

The Entries interface is imported from another component that deal with services, this is why it's exported also.

this file looks like this:

```
export interface Entry {
    label : string,
    value : number
} 

export interface Entries extends Array<Entry>{}
```

From another component, calculator.vue I am importing the Entry interface like this:

```
import { Entry } from '@/types/entries.model'
```

And I get the following error message upon complying: "Module '"../types/entries.model"' declares 'Entry' locally, but it is not exported."

What could be the reason? Should I export it somehow differently?

Thank you